# import TS file to Vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've made a ts file with an enum and interface, and I need to use them in Vue components. However, when I try to import the ts file into my Vue components, I get an error that says it can't find the module.

My src/models/Profile.ts file looks like this:

```
export enum Status {
    NONE,
    ACCEPTING,
    NOT_ACCEPTING,
}

export interface Profile {
    status: Status,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
}
```

The Vue component I'm trying to import the above:

```
import Profile from '@/models/Profile.ts';

@Component({computed: mapGetters(['user'])})
export default class CreateProfile extends Vue {
    ...
}
```

Specific error:

```
An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '@/models/Profile' instead.
```

But when I try that, I get:

```
Cannot find module '@/models/Profile'.
```

Comment: You probably need to configure path alias in tsconfig file and webpack file.

Comment: Did you add TypeScript support for your project? Is your project created from Vue cli? If yes, then you can add TS support by typing `vue add typescript`

Comment: Please try and recreate the issue in a codesandbox. It's difficult to pinpoint the exact issue without seeing your config files

Comment: did you try import {Profile} from '@/models/Profile.ts'; instead ?

Comment: any updates on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`import type { Profile } from '@/models/Profile.ts';`